# Encoding multiple states and events as time series

Tags: time-series, lstm, multilabel

I have data on a collection of entities, along with data about things that have happened to them over time. I am trying to encode this into a categorical time series for use in an LSTM neural network for sequence prediction, and I'm not sure of the best way to do this.

My exact purpose is sensitive, so I will motivate the problem using cats.

Imagine you have data on many thousands of cats. Some of the data tell you how the cats are in certain states over a period of time (e.g. "had fleas between date *a* and date *b*", "went missing between date *c* and date *d*", etc.). The cat can be in multiple states at the same time (i.e. it can both be missing and have fleas).

Some of the data tell you how specific events happened to the cat (e.g. "Got into a fight on date *e*", "vaccinated for disease *x* on date *f*", etc.)

My current plan is to encode this as a large binary indicator vector of events and states, built up by inspecting the data over a predesignated step size. So if over the span of a month, a cat is in the state of having fleas, and experiences the event of getting into a fight, the indicator vector will take values of 1 for elements corresponding to that state and event, and 0 for all other elements. I can then feed this through the LSTM with the end of predicting the state of a cat month-by-month.

I don't know if this is the best way of structuring the problem. I've had limited success finding anything in the existing literature on multi-state LSTMs.

Any suggestions, references or insight would be welcome.

Comment: Did it work? I'm facing a similar problem with entity related info over time and, as you say, it's dificult to find an example.

Comment: The application didn't work because I didn't have enough data to fit the model, but multi-state LSTM as a concept worked fine. Implemented in Keras/TensorFlow, and the only real difficulty was getting my head around the dimensionality of the LSTM cells.